# How do I convert a data table to this JSON object format in R?

Tags: r, api, httr, qualtrics, jsonlite

I'm attempting to use this Qualtrics API endpoint (https://api.qualtrics.com/0cc0b9dcffc6f-start-a-delete-survey-responses-job) with R to bulk-remove responses from a survey by using httr and jsonlite R packages. It is important to leave the data input as-is because the script should let someone copy/paste in a series of response id’s directly from an Excel doc.

Here is my current code with dummy data (everything except for the post request code):

```
install.packages(c("httr", "jsonlite"))
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

data <- read.table(text='
R_010101010101010
R_010101010101010
R_010101010101010
R_010101010101010
R_010101010101010
')
colnames(data) <- 'responseId'

allResponses <- list()
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {
  response <- list(responseId=data[row, 1],decrementQuotas=TRUE)
  allResponses <- append(allResponses, response)
}

postData <- toJSON(list(deletes=allResponses))
print(postData)
```

I’m getting an error when trying to submit the POST request because the body of the request is not the right format. It needs to be in this format:

```
{
  "deletes": [
    {
      "responseId": "R_1234",
      "decrementQuotas": true
    }
  ]
}
```

But what my code prints is this

```
{"deletes":{"responseId":["R_010101010101010"],"decrementQuotas":[true],"responseId.1":["R_010101010101010"],"decrementQuotas.1":[true],"responseId.2":["R_010101010101010"],"decrementQuotas.2":[true],"responseId.3":["R_010101010101010"],"decrementQuotas.3":[true],"responseId.4":["R_010101010101010"],"decrementQuotas.4":[true]}}
```

Can you all help me coerce this data into the correct JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with append. Right now it's not building the list the way you want. You would do the loop more like

```
allResponses <- list()
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {
  response <- list(responseId=data[row, 1],decrementQuotas=TRUE)
  allResponses <- append(allResponses, list(response))
}

postData <- toJSON(list(deletes=allResponses), auto_unbox = TRUE)
cat(postData)
# {"deletes":[{"responseId":"R_010101010101010","decrementQuotas":true},
# {"responseId":"R_010101010101010","decrementQuotas":true},
# {"responseId":"R_010101010101010","decrementQuotas":true},
# {"responseId":"R_010101010101010","decrementQuotas":true},
# {"responseId":"R_010101010101010","decrementQuotas":true}]}
```

Here we also use `auto_unbox` to remove the extra brackets

But rather than usign the loop, a better way to make the list would be to use something like `lapply` in the first place

```
allResponses <- lapply(1:nrow(data), function(row) {
  list(responseId=data[row, 1],decrementQuotas=TRUE)
})
```

No need for the loop and append in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much! I’m still getting a 400 after using the lapply code you suggested, but this time it’s for the decrementQuotas data type: ($meta$httpStatus
[1] "400 - Bad Request"

$meta$error
$meta$error$errorCode
[1] "QVAL_4"

$meta$error$errorMessage
[1] "Parameter decrementQuotas should have a boolean value, found ")

Comment: What are you doing with the `postData` after you create it? It's odd the error message doesn't find any value at all. Are you sure you have the right message format?

Comment: Just sending off the POST request. 
res <- POST(
  url = api_url, 
  body = postData, 
  add_headers(.headers = c(
    'X-API-TOKEN'= api_token, 
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    ))
  )
print(content(res))

Your for loop solution works like a charm, but it looks like the lapply alternative puts the decrementQuotas value into brackets for some reason

Comment: Since you are encoding the data manually, try setting `encode="raw"` when you call `POST`. You still need to use `auto_unbox=TRUE` whether you use the loop or the `lapply` solution.